# Practicing proofs for Discrete math, have been stuck on these for a few days

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1)Suppose M={(n,m)|n,m are natural numbers and n =mq for some q in n}.? 
check if the following properties hold. If it does prove it if not show counter example.

a, Reflexivity
b. Symmetry
c. Transitivity

2) Prove for any sets A and B, P(A) is subset of P(B) iff A is subset of B.
show 3 test cases and prove the results

Comment: That looks like a homework exercise. Do you have any question _about_ this exercise you want to ask?

Comment: Not HW. just additional exercises from my book. Im not sure where to start with #1
 for #2 my best guess is
Suppose A is a subset of B. let x be in P(A), then x is a subset of A by definition of powerset. Because A is a subset of B.Therefore x is in P(B) by def. of powerset. therefore for this condition it holds for elements P(A) subset P(B). Not sure what it means by proving 3 test cases though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but some hints:

For 1:

What does $n=mq$ say about $m$ and $n$ in terms of divisibility? What do Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive mean in this context? (Should help you see where to go with this).

For 2:

You have the right idea for the if direction: $A\subset B\Rightarrow P(A)\subset P(B)$. The trickier part is proving the other direction, but the strategy is the same (note: use the fact that you know $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are power sets and that $A\in P(A)\subset P(B)$.)

Comment: I figured out part 2 but still stuck on part 1. Is M a relation? and the all of the natural numbers are the set?

Comment: @user382899: $M$ is a relation on $\Bbb N$; it’s members are *ordered pairs* of natural numbers. In ordinary English, $n\mathrel{M}m$ says that $n$ is a multiple of $m$.